# Parsed Console Output Error in Hudson

Tags: hudson

im running Hudson continuous integration for db unit.

when i run the job the console output is displaying the SUCCESS, but then why do the Parsed Console Output keep returning this error:

```
ERROR:Failed to parse console log :
log-parser plugin ERROR: Cannot parse log: Can't read parsing rules file:
```

i already installed the parse-log plugin & i already restarted the Hudson..

i installed the plugin using remote PC

any help and suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1) Place the Parser Rule File in the JENKINS_HOME location.
2) Configure that log parser console output in the Global COnfiguration settings and Name it.
3) Add this option in the Post Build Actions and Select the Name

Answer (score 1):

ok silly me..

i forgot to configure the global configuration in hudson that link to the parser rule file..

problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this in case anyone else has a specific case of this problem.  This issue started when upgrading from 1.509.2 to 1.554.3...  I had the parsing rules file in the win\system folder which was a known issue when running Jenkins as a service.  Well I guess they fixed it by this version.  I moved the parsing rules back into Jenkins Home folder and it worked fine again.